# OTP phone Verification on register button in laravel 10

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backend

I want to create otp for user authentication and I bought a web service and now I can't register it on the submit button.
and i have no idea where to start
i tried put it in register control and put it in register form but nothing happend
this is a example code that i got from the web service i bought:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$sms_client = new SoapClient('http://payamak-service.ir/SendService.svc?wsdl', array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

try {
    $parameters['userName'] = "userName";
    $parameters['password'] = "password";
    $parameters['fromNumber'] = "fromNumber";
    $parameters['toNumbers'] = array("toNumbers");
    $parameters['messageContent'] = "hello";
    $parameters['isFlash'] = false;
    $recId = array(0);
    $status = 0x0;
    $parameters['recId'] = &$recId ;
    $parameters['status'] = &$status ;
    echo $sms_client->SendSMS($parameters)->SendSMSResult;
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

this is my register controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:11', 'unique:users'],
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

this my register form :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<form method="POST" class="py-3 px-md-5 px-3" action="{{ route('register') }}" id="register">
  @csrf
    <h3>ثبت‌نام
        صفحه 
        <span class="text-danger_cs">50 نکته</span>
    </h3>

    <div class="row mb-3 mt-3">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="name" class=" @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" name="name" placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" > 

            @error('name')
            <span class="invalid-feedback text-end mt-2" role="alert">
                <strong class="text-danger_cs" dir="rtl"> نام و نام خانوادگی وارد شده یا شماره تلفن وارد شده از قبل وجود دارد</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="row mb-3">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="تلفن همراه" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required autocomplete="phone">

            @error('phone')
            <span class="invalid-feedback text-end mt-2" role="alert">
                <strong class="text-danger_cs" dir="rtl">شماره تلفن وارد شده غلط است !</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="رمز عبور" required autocomplete="new-password">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-eye" id="togglePassword" onclick="showpass()"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="تائید رمز عبور" required autocomplete="new-password">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-eye" id="confirm_eye" onclick="showconfirmpass()"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" onclick="sms()" class="btn bg-danger_cs w-75 mt-0 text-white p-2">
            {{ __('ثبت‌نام') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
@if (Route::has('login'))
<div class="row mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <a class="text-center btn bg-danger_cs text-white mt-0 w-75 mt-2" href="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ __('قبلا ثبت‌نام کردی؟') }}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
</form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel? and Which package are you using for Authentication?

Comment: Which web service did you pay for? Does it have a public website link for reference?

Comment: im using laravel 10 and im using vue for auth

Comment: i payed niazpardaz ..... it's a persian webservice

Comment: I mean which php package are you using for auth? Did you create this registerController by yourself?

Comment: i used Vue auth package

Comment: If you paid for the web service, shouldn't they also provide you with technical support?

Comment: yeah that's right but i live in iran there is no rule around here

Comment: If you're using Vue Auth package then how come the blade view there? It is supposed to be Vue files right?

Comment: If you're setting up a new project I suggest you to use any of the default Laravel Authentication packages like Breeze or Jetstream.

Comment: i'm used vue auth package in laravel

Comment: it is not clear where your issue is, however, in general, you will need to define a new endpoint to send the OTP, and validate the sent OTP in the register route

Comment: hi hassan how am i suppose to do that?